# Nemerle Extension Property

Tags: nemerle

Recently there was a discussion about adding Extension Property to Nemerle language.
But the syntax is unclear.

Updated proposed syntax:

```cs
module MExtension
{
  [ExtensionProperty(string)] public StringProp : int    { get; set; } 
  [ExtensionProperty(int)]    public IntProp    : string { get { "abc" } }
}

module MTest
{
  F() : void
  {
    def x : int = "ab".StringProp;
    "abc".StringProp = 100;

    def y : string = 10.IntProp;
  }
}
```

Note: module == static class

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it because of duplication:

1. you should specify Type2 in two points,
2. you should specify PropName in two points.

So the refactoring can be slightly complicated. How about the following approach?

```
module MExtension
{
  property PropName(this arg : Type1) : Type2
  {
    get
    {
      ...
    }
    set
    {
      ... = value
    }
  }
}
```

or even autoproperty:

```
module MExtension
{
  property PropName(this arg : Type1) : Type2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: To use your syntax there must be a special keyword "property" to disambiguate it from method.  
  

    public property ExtensionProperty(this arg : Type1) : Type2 { }
    public ExtensionMethod(this arg : Type1) : Type2 { ... }

  
It is not good because it breaks old code.  
  
Then it is better to add attribute like [ExtensionProperty].  
  
Or perhaps using other parenthesis. Not () , but {} for instance.

Comment: Actually, my idea was generally based on macros with whatever is an underlying implementation. "property" could be a macros which converts the declaration in anything appropriate.

Comment: I see , but it is not possible to do it using only macros. Because you must have syntax extension   SomeObject.SomeProperty.  This must be done in the compiler core, and.  Macro can be helpful to reduce code, for instance if you take the possible syntax of explicit get_ , set_ methods.


You solution is good enough , but other braces must be used to make clear distinction from extension methods.
I think using {} the best, cause () is used for methods and [] is used for indexers.

public MyProp : int {this m : Type1} { get; set; }